# exclude properties with empty object type from type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have the following type in typescript:

```
type Foo = {
             x: {}; 
             y: {bar: string};
             z: {};
};
```

How can I drop all the empty properties (i.e. `x` and `z`) so that the resulting type will look like this?

```
type Result = {
     y: {bar: string};
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With just your one example it's not clear which types other than literally `{}` you'd be okay with dropping: for example, do you need to keep or drop [the `object` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#object-type)?  What about [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown)? I'm not going to worry about this too much; just know that you should probably run through a suite of possible edge cases and figure out if the behavior of any type you come up with is acceptable.

Anyway, one possible implementation that doesn't rely on importing external libraries is:

```
type DropEmpty<T> =
  { [K in keyof T as keyof T[K] extends never ? never : K]: T[K] };
```

This is using [key remapping in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#key-remapping-in-mapped-types) to suppress any properties matching a certain criterion, by remapping the key in question to `never`.

You can verify that this behaves as desired for your example:

```
type Result = DropEmpty<Foo>
/*type Result = {
    y: {
        bar: string;
    };
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFKAPAXGgXwG5MoR9UoAjAQwCd8BnYOgSwDsBzKY0gLwq9e6dKEhQAInThgAogFswoADwAVAHzJSlANoBpKBygBrCCDgAzKKqg1GJs5ev6AulAjZgEdgBN77CAA3CDooAH4oAODQ-D0XfFVXHhIsUXBoACUIRgBXABtgZElpOUUVeDh1dAB6ACoxTOz8wpQMLCxyNFJ29toGKGY2LhT2oSha6qA)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but it feels a bit verbose:

```
import type {ConditionalExcept} from 'type-fest';

type DropEmpty<T> = Pick<
  T,
  keyof ConditionalExcept<
    {
      [Property in keyof T]: keyof T[Property];
    },
    never
  >
>;
```

This produces the desired result:

```
type Foo = {
  x: {}; 
  y: {bar: string};
  z: {};
};
type Result = DropEmpty<Foo>;
```

Live example on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/drop-empty-properties-eu0l8